# why i am getting UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from random import choice

def get_proxy():
        url = "https://free-proxy-list.net/"

        r = requests.get(url)
        soup =BeautifulSoup(r.content , 'lxml')
        return{'https': choice(list(map(lambda x:x[0]+':'+x[1],list(zip(map(lambda x:x.text, soup.findAll('td')[::8]),map(lambda x:x.text, soup.findAll('td')[1::8]))))))}

def proxy_request(request_type, url, **kwargs):
    while 1:
        try:
            proxy = get_proxy()
            print("using proxy: {}".format(proxy))
            r = requests.request(request_type, url, proxies=proxy, timeout=7, **kwargs)
            num = soup.find_all('h1')
            print (num.text())
            break
        except:
            pass

        return r
r = proxy_request('get',"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page")
print (r.text())
```

and i am getting this error

Comment: You haven't included the error. Please show that and the traceback.

Comment: Side note: I hope never to have to maintain `return{'https': choice(list(map(lambda x:x[0]+':'+x[1],list(zip(map(lambda x:x.text, soup.findAll('td')[::8]),map(lambda x:x.text, soup.findAll('td')[1::8]))))))}`

Comment: using proxy: {'https': '131.161.210.40:32821'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/imac/Documents/trying auto ips.py", line 24, in <module>
    r.text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
>>> 
============= this is the error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `return` is in your `while` loop. When you `break`, you skip `return`, therefore `r` is `None`:

```
def proxy_request(request_type, url, **kwargs):
    while 1:
        try:
            proxy = get_proxy()
            print("using proxy: {}".format(proxy))
            r = requests.request(request_type, url, proxies=proxy, timeout=7, **kwargs)
            num = soup.find_all('h1')
            print (num.text())
            break
        except:
            pass

    return num  # return it here, outside of the while loop
```

You'll also want to consider the case where `num` might *not* be found and get a case to break out to avoid infinite loops